# Changing any of the option bytes leads to increase of read protection level in STM32F407

Tags: embedded, stm32f4discovery, bare-metal

I have asked this question on ST forums and didn't get a helpful response, just thought somebody could help me here.

I am facing a kind of strange problem with no explanation. actually, I have been digging through the reference manual for a day now.

currently, I am implementing my own version of bare-metal for the embedded flash memory in STM32F407. The problem is that whenever I try to modify options bytes of the flash memory, it behaves as expected but when I power off and then power on my board, the read protection level is always set 1 even if I set it to 0 in the code.

Not only that but even if the board is still connected and I end the debug session after modifying boot options leaving RDP to level 0, when I start a new debugging session, I can't, simply because RDP is set to level 1 by itself.

I actually read in the reference manual `page 93` this line:

> • Level 1:
>
> read protection enabled It is the default read protection
> level after option byte erase.

but still don't know what it has to do with RDP level.

Here is my code:

```c
HAL_FLASH_ErrStates_t HAL_FLASH_Init()
{
    // local used variables
    uint16_t local_u16TempVal = 0;
    uint8_t local_u32Counter = 0;
    uint8_t local_u8TempBitPos = 0;
    uint8_t local_u8SectorsLength = sizeof globalConstArr_SectorsConfig_t / sizeof globalConstArr_SectorsConfig_t[0];
    HAL_FLASH_ErrStates_t local_errState_t = HAL_FLASH_OK;

    // check for errors
    for (local_u32Counter = 0; local_u32Counter < local_u8SectorsLength; local_u32Counter++) // if you want to improve code, unroll this for loop for 11 lines of code
    {
        if (globalConstArr_SectorsConfig_t[local_u32Counter].WriteProtection >= LIB_CONSTANTS_MAX_DRIVER_STATE || globalConstArr_SectorsConfig_t[local_u32Counter].SectorNumber >= HAL_FLASH_MAX_MAIN_MEM_SECTOR)
        {
            local_errState_t = HAL_FLASH_ERR_INVALID_CONFIG;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            // do nothing
        }
    }
    if (globalConstArr_FlashConfig_t[0].DataCacheEnabled >= LIB_CONSTANTS_MAX_DRIVER_STATE || globalConstArr_FlashConfig_t[0].InstructionCacheEnabled >= LIB_CONSTANTS_MAX_DRIVER_STATE || globalConstArr_FlashConfig_t[0].PrefetchEnabled >= LIB_CONSTANTS_MAX_DRIVER_STATE || globalConstArr_FlashConfig_t[0].WaitStates >= HAL_FLASH_MAX_WAIT_STATE || globalConstArr_FlashConfig_t[0].LockConfiguration >= LIB_CONSTANTS_MAX_LOCK_STATE || globalConstArr_FlashConfig_t[0].InterruptsEnabled >= LIB_CONSTANTS_MAX_DRIVER_STATE || globalConstArr_FlashConfig_t[0].ProgramSize >= HAL_FLASH_MAX_PROGRAM_SIZE || globalConstArr_FlashConfig_t[0].ReadProtectionLevel >= HAL_FLASH_MAX_READ_PROTECT_LVL || globalConstArr_MiscellaneousConfig_t[0].ResetOnStandBy >= LIB_CONSTANTS_MAX_DRIVER_STATE || globalConstArr_MiscellaneousConfig_t[0].ResetOnStop >= LIB_CONSTANTS_MAX_DRIVER_STATE || globalConstArr_MiscellaneousConfig_t[0].IndependentWatchDogType >= HAL_FLASH_MAX_INDPEND_WATCH_DOG_TYPE || globalConstArr_MiscellaneousConfig_t[0].BrownoutResetLevel >= HAL_FLASH_MAX_BROWN_RESET_LVL)
    {
        local_errState_t = HAL_FLASH_ERR_INVALID_CONFIG;
    }
    else
    {
        // do nothing
    }

    // check for busy wait or not
    local_errState_t = HAL_FLASH_GetHardwareErrors();
    if (local_errState_t == HAL_FLASH_ERR_FLASH_BUSY && globalConstArr_FlashConfig_t[0].InterruptsEnabled == LIB_CONSTANTS_DISABLED)
    {
        // busy wait
        while (LIB_MATH_BTT_GET_BIT(global_pFlashReg_t->FLASH_SR, HAL_FLASH_SR_BSY) == 1)
        {
        };
        local_errState_t = HAL_FLASH_OK;
    }

    // main function
    if (local_errState_t == HAL_FLASH_OK)
    {
        // unlock all configuration registers
        global_pFlashReg_t->FLASH_KEYR = HAL_FLASH_CR_KEY1;
        global_pFlashReg_t->FLASH_KEYR = HAL_FLASH_CR_KEY2;
        global_pFlashReg_t->FLASH_OPTKEYR = HAL_FLASH_OPTCR_OPTKEY1;
        global_pFlashReg_t->FLASH_OPTKEYR = HAL_FLASH_OPTCR_OPTKEY2;

        // assign global configuration variables
        global_u8BehaviorType = globalConstArr_FlashConfig_t[0].InterruptsEnabled == LIB_CONSTANTS_ENABLED ? HAL_FLASH_CONFIG_VAL_OPERATION_TYPE_INTERRUPT : HAL_FLASH_CONFIG_VAL_OPERATION_TYPE_BLOCKING;

        // configure flash & sectors
        LIB_MATH_BTT_ASSIGN_BIT(global_pFlashReg_t->FLASH_ACR, HAL_FLASH_ACR_DCEN, globalConstArr_FlashConfig_t[0].DataCacheEnabled);
        LIB_MATH_BTT_ASSIGN_BIT(global_pFlashReg_t->FLASH_ACR, HAL_FLASH_ACR_ICEN, globalConstArr_FlashConfig_t[0].InstructionCacheEnabled);
        LIB_MATH_BTT_ASSIGN_BIT(global_pFlashReg_t->FLASH_ACR, HAL_FLASH_ACR_PRFTEN, globalConstArr_FlashConfig_t[0].PrefetchEnabled);
        LIB_MATH_BTT_ASSIGN_BITS(global_pFlashReg_t->FLASH_ACR, HAL_FLASH_ACR_LATENCY, globalConstArr_FlashConfig_t[0].WaitStates, 3);
        LIB_MATH_BTT_ASSIGN_BIT(global_pFlashReg_t->FLASH_CR, HAL_FLASH_CR_ERRIE, globalConstArr_FlashConfig_t[0].InterruptsEnabled);
        LIB_MATH_BTT_ASSIGN_BIT(global_pFlashReg_t->FLASH_CR, HAL_FLASH_CR_EOPIE, globalConstArr_FlashConfig_t[0].InterruptsEnabled);
        LIB_MATH_BTT_ASSIGN_BITS(global_pFlashReg_t->FLASH_CR, HAL_FLASH_CR_PSIZE, globalConstArr_FlashConfig_t[0].ProgramSize, 2);

        for (local_u32Counter = 0; local_u32Counter < local_u8SectorsLength; local_u32Counter++) // if you want to improve code, unroll this for loop for 11 lines of code
        {
            local_u8TempBitPos = LIB_MATH_BTT_u8GetMSBSetPos(globalConstArr_SectorsConfig_t[local_u32Counter].SectorNumber);
            local_u16TempVal |= (!globalConstArr_SectorsConfig_t[local_u32Counter].WriteProtection << local_u8TempBitPos);
        }

        LIB_MATH_BTT_ASSIGN_BITS(global_pFlashReg_t->FLASH_OPTCR, HAL_FLASH_OPTCR_nWRP, local_u16TempVal, 12);

        LIB_MATH_BTT_ASSIGN_BIT(global_pFlashReg_t->FLASH_OPTCR, HAL_FLASH_OPTCR_nRST_STDBY, !globalConstArr_MiscellaneousConfig_t[0].ResetOnStandBy);
        LIB_MATH_BTT_ASSIGN_BIT(global_pFlashReg_t->FLASH_OPTCR, HAL_FLASH_OPTCR_nRST_STOP, !globalConstArr_MiscellaneousConfig_t[0].ResetOnStop);
        LIB_MATH_BTT_ASSIGN_BIT(global_pFlashReg_t->FLASH_OPTCR, HAL_FLASH_OPTCR_WDG_SW, globalConstArr_MiscellaneousConfig_t[0].IndependentWatchDogType);
        LIB_MATH_BTT_ASSIGN_BITS(global_pFlashReg_t->FLASH_OPTCR, HAL_FLASH_OPTCR_BOR_LEV, globalConstArr_MiscellaneousConfig_t[0].BrownoutResetLevel, 2);

        LIB_MATH_BTT_ASSIGN_BITS(global_pFlashReg_t->FLASH_OPTCR, HAL_FLASH_OPTCR_RDP, globalConstArr_FlashConfig_t[0].ReadProtectionLevel, 8);

        // lock configuration if configured
        LIB_MATH_BTT_ASSIGN_BIT(global_pFlashReg_t->FLASH_CR, HAL_FLASH_CR_LOCK, globalConstArr_FlashConfig_t[0].LockConfiguration);
        LIB_MATH_BTT_ASSIGN_BIT(global_pFlashReg_t->FLASH_OPTCR, HAL_FLASH_OPTCR_OPTLOCK, globalConstArr_FlashConfig_t[0].LockConfiguration);

        // save the values // TODO: Uncomment these lines after resolving readout protection level increase error
        LIB_MATH_BTT_SET_BIT(global_pFlashReg_t->FLASH_OPTCR, HAL_FLASH_OPTCR_OPTSTRT);
        while (LIB_MATH_BTT_GET_BIT(global_pFlashReg_t->FLASH_SR, HAL_FLASH_SR_BSY) == 1)
        {
        };

        // check for errors
        local_errState_t = HAL_FLASH_GetHardwareErrors();
        if (local_errState_t == HAL_FLASH_ERR_FLASH_BUSY && globalConstArr_FlashConfig_t[0].InterruptsEnabled == LIB_CONSTANTS_DISABLED)
        {
            // busy wait
            while (LIB_MATH_BTT_GET_BIT(global_pFlashReg_t->FLASH_SR, HAL_FLASH_SR_BSY) == 1)
            {
            };
            local_errState_t = HAL_FLASH_OK;
        }
        local_errState_t = HAL_FLASH_ERR_FLASH_BUSY ? HAL_FLASH_OK : local_errState_t;
    }

    return local_errState_t;
}
```

**PS:** The problem is solved when I comment below these lines which are responsible for saving option values:

```c
// save the values
LIB_MATH_BTT_SET_BIT(global_pFlashReg_t->FLASH_OPTCR, HAL_FLASH_OPTCR_OPTSTRT);
while (LIB_MATH_BTT_GET_BIT(global_pFlashReg_t->FLASH_SR, HAL_FLASH_SR_BSY) == 1)
{
};
```

and this image is from stm32cubeide:
[image]